# Remove focus border of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I remove the border with appears when focusing an EditText View?

I need it cause this view has little space in the screen, but without the border it's enough. When running on Emulator an orange border appears, on Device a blue one.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible... You can always make your custom buttons, a little bit smaller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edittext - how to hide underbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975528/edittext-how-to-hide-underbar)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Have you tried setting the background of the `EditText` to a transparent colour?

```
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:hint="@string/hello" 
android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

Comment: `"@android:color/transparent"` is a bit more self-explaining.

Comment: `"@null"` can also be an option

Comment: this answer is not correct, as it not only removes the focus border, but also the not focused EditText background.

Comment: @Michael yes, because hex 0 and 00000 is the same. its still zero.

Answer (score 39):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"                 

 />
```

Answer (score 12):

It is possible. However I would not recommend it because users are used to certain metaphors and you should not change the general UX.

You can apply different styles to your views. In your case it sounds like you want an EditText View element which looks like a TextView element. In this case you would have to specify other backgrounds for the EditText depending on the state of the View element.

In your desired layout.xml you assign a background to your EditText:

```
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:hint="@string/hello" android:background="@drawable/custom"
/>
```

Then you create the custom.xml in your drawable folder and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
</selector>
```

Those are the possible states of your EditText View element. Normally you can access Android platform drawables directly by using `@android:drawable/textfield_default`, but in this case the textfield drawables are private so you have to copy them into your own drawable folder. The original resources can be found in your SDK installation folder at `ANDROID_HOME\platforms\android-(API LEVEL)\data\res\drawable-(*dpi)\`.

Once you are done you end up with an EditText which looks like a TextView but completely without those borders. Those orange borders you saw in the emulator are the default Android drawables. The blue ones are vendor specific (possibly Samsung).

Hope that helped and didn't confuse that much.

Comment: I'm going to test it soon. And it's for Galaxy Tab.

Comment: well.. this can work. But I don't want to draw all those backgrounds. I need just remove the border of the Default one, this ins't possible?

Comment: The example which I posted is a derived from the original implementation. The EditText border is not drawn individually. It is a complete background image which is set depending on the current state of the View element. Internally the android platform sets a complete background image every time. You can see the nine-patch images in your SDK installation at ANDROID_HOME\platforms\android-(API LEVEL)\data\res\drawable-(*dpi)\.

Answer (score 6):

This is the fastest solution:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:background="#00000000"                 

 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the background color as transparent to remove the EditText border on focus.

Method 1

```
<EditText 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000"
/>
```