# EditText without line at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to make my edit text field without the line at the bottom, like in this picture
[image]
Right now my edit text looks like this
[image]
How can I do it?

Comment: Set background of the edittext as @null

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975528/edittext-how-to-hide-underbar.Please check SO before asking

Comment: I did searched, and didnt found anything...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

You can make it by setting the background to null

Answer (score 6):

Try below code:-

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

above code do transparent your edittext background.

Answer (score 3):

You can get `transparent background` of `EditText` by using

```
 android:background="#00000000"
```

or

```
 android:background="@null"
```

or

You can create `custom drawable.xml`, and just make the `drawable transparent` and use

```
android:background="@drawable/customdrawable"
```