# EditText: How to show cursor and hide underline at a time?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm developing an Calculator App. I wanna achieve the UI as like as Android default Calculator App. Please check my App's screenshot.

[image]

I want to hide the underline of `EditText` and show the cursor in `white` color. I used transparent background at EditText (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975575/6200296)) also used background as `@null`. It hides EditText's underline and also hide the cursor. BUT... for calculator App cursor should not be hidden.

Please give me a way to hide underline of `EditText` and show the EditText's cursor of white color.

Comment: `edittext.setBackground(null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the background drawable as transparent and set the Text Cursor drawable of your choice. For Example:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/remarkEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white"/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It works!
I've just created a custom cursor drawable like:

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>`
</shape>

Answer (score 2):

Set the background drawable as transparent and set the android:textCursorDrawable null so the cursor color always text color. For Example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

please add one more thing in your `EditText` :=

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/youId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Progamatically you could set the `EditText` background filter into this. This would set it into a clear background color.

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Or via XML you can do this, but this would only work for Android API 21 +, your best option is the color filter.

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

For the cursor, you should add `textCursorDrawable` with `cursorVisible` via XML.