# How can remove underline from TextInputLayout or TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, xml

I want remove underline.

[image: Picture showing an underline on Android]

This is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/register_hint_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: just set `android:background="@null"`

Answer (score 1):

set background like this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

you can also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975575/7543081)

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:background=""` inside TextInputEditText

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a layout file for the background you wish and set it as:
`android:background="@layout/nameoffile"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set below attributes in `TextInputLayout` to have no width

```
app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
```

Your layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/register_hint_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Preview

[image]