# How to remove the underline under TextInputLayout in Android Material Design?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design

I was trying to remove the underline from a material design component named `TextInputLayout`. I have tried several different answers from SO which didn't work out for me so I decided to ask my own question.

**How can I remove this underline?**

[image]

XML:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            style="?colorOnPrimary"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:startIconContentDescription="Heading">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntubold"
                android:hint="Heading"
                android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274302/14493188)? I just tested and `android:background="@null"` works for me. You can add a list of answers that you have tried so that we do not need to ask what you have tried.

Comment: Yeah I did. It just removed the background completely. I mean the gray background

Comment: Did you add `android:background="@null"` to the `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`?

Comment: I tried adding for both container and the edittext. Same thing happened

Comment: Add the xml so I can test it

Comment: Done. I have updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226445/discussion-between-matias-lappalainen-and-michael-grigoryan).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the material design guideline, this is activation indicator of TextInputLayout.

Check [Activation indicator attributes](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field) for details.

One solution is to override some of those attributes inside your app.

Or you can do something like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            style="?colorOnPrimary"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:startIconContentDescription="Heading"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntubold"
        android:hint="Heading"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Check `app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"` and `app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has fixed my problem. By the way can you provide the link to that part of the documentation

Comment: https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field you have to manually find the text "Activation indicator attributes". Didn't find any anchor for this part.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the underline you should create a theme and a style for your TextInputLayout

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.SearchBarTheme.TextInputLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>
</style>
```

After that, asign that theme to the view

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/ily"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Whatever you want"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```