# How to make focus indicator (the orange rectange) invisible in google TV?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-tv

When I applied the following selector for a TextView in a ListView, the indicator for listItem disappear.

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
      android:drawable="@color/myGreenLight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/myGreenDark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> 
</selector>
```

But is there anyway to disable the indicator for the overall project?

Comment: Please elaborate your question . I am unable to get your issue.

Comment: @Grishu: By default, Google TV will automatically add an orange rectange to the border of a clickable view when it is focused. And I want to disable that function.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar problem.  One of those answers might be able to applied to your situation.

[Remove focus border of EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478109/remove-focus-border-of-edittext)

The question being why would you want to get rid of the selector highlight?  How will the user know the item is selected?

Comment: I want to use some customized indicators for selected items